# How to Update just one field in Yii2 with custom button, and not all records?

Tags: php, yii2

I'm really new to yii2 and looking forward to post as few questions as I can.
I would like to update a data field with curdate() when a button is pressed.. but currently, pressing the button updates ALL the records:

```
 [
        'class' => 'kartik\grid\ActionColumn',
        'header' => 'Aggiorna',
        'template' => '{my_button}',
        'buttons' => [
            'my_button' => function ($url, $model, $key) {
             return Html::button('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-link"> 
             </span>',
             ['value'=>Yii::$app->db
                       ->createCommand("UPDATE 
                       qual_lab_sistema_qualita_attivita SET 
                       data_ultimo_invio=CURDATE() 
                       WHERE id= '$model->id' ;")
                       ->execute(),
                       'class' => 'btn btn-default btn-xs', 
                       'id'=>'modalButtonView',
                        ]);;
            }
        ],
        'options' => [
            'width' => '20',
            ],
    ],
```

Can u help me pleasE? 
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't work this way. You should send HTTP request to your controller's action for this. For example with AJAX.

```
[
    'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
    'buttons' => [
        'my_button' => function ($url, $model, $key) {
            return Html::button('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-link"></span>', [
                'onclick' => "
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'DELETE',
                        url: '" . Url::to(['update-item', 'id' => $model->primaryKey]) . "',
                        dataType: 'json'
                    }).done(function(){alert('Updated');});
                ",
            ]);
        }
    ],
],
```

And create action

```
public function actionUpdateItem($id)
{
    \Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;

    $updatedRows = \Yii::$app->db
        ->createCommand()
        ->update('{{qual_lab_sistema_qualita_attivita }}', [
            'data_ultimo_invio' => new \yii\db\Expression("NOW()")
        ], ['id' => $id])
        ->execute();

   return [];
}
```

Comment: oh, I get it.. but can you help me understand why the query works half way? I mean, it updates all the db records.. not only the one where i press the button

Comment: @lordcroci in your example every button runs query on render HTML. It's HTML and PHP integration basics.

Comment: I'm getting this error in the console inspection of the chrome browser when i click the button.. 

UPDATE qbase.ase-spa.com/index.php/qual-lab-sistema-qualita-attivita/… 500 (Internal Server Error) 
send @ jquery.js:9175 
ajax @ jquery.js:8656 
onclick @ index?sort=attivita&page=1&per-page=10:574 

can't understand what can be.. do u have any idea?

Comment: Ok The problem was a space after the table name.. nothing big. 
Is there a way to check with a pop up if the user is sure to update the record? 
Thanks!

Comment: @lordcroci `'onclick' => "if (confirm('Sure?')) {/* script here */}"`

Comment: Thanks a lot! I figured it out a couple of hours ago. Thanks anyway to be so kind!